# Angular routing not working i firebase hosting

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular-routing, firebase-hosting

I have a Angular project where routing works in localhost, but when I deploy my project to Firebase hosting only the base-url works. 
Here is my routing: Example https://baseurl/jegharaldrigkategori does not work in Firbase hosting. It says "Page not found"

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home', 
      pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'jegharaldrigkategori', 
    component: JegharaldrigkategoriComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'jegharaldrig', 
    component: JegharaldrigComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'udfordring', 
    component: UdfordringComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'terning', 
    component: TerningComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'overunder', 
    component: OverunderComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: What does your `firebase.json` config look like? Is it setup to serve `index.html` for all paths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When hosting on firebase you must remember to redirect all calls to `index.html`.

The hosting portion of your `firebase.json` should include "rewrites", here's an example :

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I got the same error. I did this in `firebase.json` & firebase 404 page is not showing up. But now my theme's 404 error page is opening. But in my route there is a valid URL. Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you rephrase @Sayandeep?